# Image of group morphism is abelian implies domain is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

If $f$ is a non-trivial group morphism and if for all $g_1,g_2$, we have $f(g_1)f(g_2) = f(g_2)f(g_1) $ i.e. image is abelian. Does that imply $g_1g_2 = g_2g_1$ i.e. the domain is abelian?

I have been unable to prove this statement, so I thought I would construct a counter-example. However, to do that would require that my domain be a non-abelian group (for example, some $S_n$ or dihedral group) - however, I don't have much proof-related experience in constructing group morphisms yet, so I was unable to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: There's a homomorphism from $S_3$ onto the cyclic group of order $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any two groups A and B, with A non-abelian and B abelian and non-trivial, and consider the projections $A\times B\to B$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Bbb Q_8$ be the quaternions.   All it's subgroups are normal.   Take any non-trivial one.   Say $H=\{\pm1\}$.

Then do the canonical projection:   $\Bbb Q_8\to \Bbb Q_8/H$.

$\Bbb Q_8$ is not abelian.   But since the quotient has order $4$, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Consider

$$\begin{align}
\varphi: S_3&\to \Bbb Z_2,\\
r^is^j&\mapsto s^j,
\end{align}$$

where $S_3=\langle r,s\mid r^3, s^2, srs=r^{-1}\rangle $.

Comment: If anyone is asking this in all likelihood they don't know what a group presentation is...

Comment: That's a fair comment, @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez. Thank you. I will leave this as an answer for those who do . . .

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your question, there is no reason that $f(g_1)f(g_2) = f(g_2)f(g_1)$ implies commutativity in the domain group.

For example take $G = \{$ similarities in $\mathbb{R}^3 \}$, and $f: G \to \mathbb{R}^+$ where $f(s) =$ similarity ratio of $s$.
$f$ is a group morphism from $(G, \circ)$ to $(\mathbb{R}^+, \times)$. However $(\mathbb{R}^+, \times)$ is abelian but not $(G, \circ)$.